# Angular Material Autocomplete from URL

Tags: angularjs, httprequest, angular-material

I finished to acheive what I expected, but something don't work as I want.
I mean each time I fill input with new letters, all JSON is read again, and what I expect is to load JSON through a http request and apply filters directly on pre-loaded data.

My code below.

Controller

```
 (function () {
    'use strict';
    angular.module('MyApp').controller('DemoCtrl', DemoCtrl);

    function DemoCtrl($timeout, $q, $log, $http) {
        var self = this;
        self.simulateQuery = false;
        self.isDisabled = false;
        self.querySearch = querySearch;
        self.selectedItemChange = selectedItemChange;
        self.searchTextChange = searchTextChange;

        function querySearch(query) {
            return $http.get("data.json").then(function (result) {
                var results = query ? result.data.filter(createFilterFor(query)) : result.data,
                    deferred;
                return results;
            })
        }

        function searchTextChange(text) {
            $log.info('Text changed to ' + text);
        }

        function selectedItemChange(item) {
            $log.info('Item changed to ' + JSON.stringify(item.NAME));
        }

        function createFilterFor(query) {
            //  var lowercaseQuery = angular.lowercase(query);
            var lowercaseQuery = query;
            return function filterFn(item) {
                return (item.NAME.indexOf(lowercaseQuery) === 0);
            };
        }
    }
})();
```

Html

```
 <html>

<head>
    <script src='https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.4/angular.js'>


    </script>
    <script src='https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.4/angular-animate.min.js'>


    </script>
    <script src='https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.4/angular-route.min.js'></script>
    <script src='https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.4/angular-aria.min.js'></script>
    <script src='https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.4/angular-messages.min.js'></script>
    <script src='https://gitcdn.xyz/repo/angular/bower-material/v0.11.0/angular-material.js'></script>
    <script src='https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/t-114/assets-cache.js'></script>
    <script src='script.js'></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angular_material/0.10.0/angular-material.min.css"> </head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css"> </head>

<body>
    <div ng-controller="DemoCtrl as ctrl" layout="column" ng-cloak="" class="autocompletedemoCustomTemplate" ng-app="MyApp">
        <md-content layout-padding="" layout="column">
            <form ng-submit="$event.preventDefault()">
                <md-autocomplete ng-disabled="ctrl.isDisabled" md-no-cache="ctrl.noCache" md-selected-item="ctrl.selectedItem" md-search-text-change="ctrl.searchTextChange(ctrl.searchText)" md-search-text="ctrl.searchText" md-selected-item-change="ctrl.selectedItemChange(item)" md-items="item in ctrl.querySearch(ctrl.searchText)" md-item-text="item.NAME" md-min-length="0" placeholder="Pick an NAME" md-menu-class="autocomplete-custom-template">
                    <md-item-template> <span class="item-title">

            <span> {{item.NAME}} </span> </span> <span class="item-metadata">
            <span class="item-metastat">
              <strong>{{item.Environnement}}</strong> 
            </span> <span class="item-metastat">
              <strong>{{item.Location}}</strong> 
            </span> </span>
                    </md-item-template>
                </md-autocomplete>
            </form>
        </md-content>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

data.json

```
[  
  {  
    "NAME":"name1",
    "Environnement":"Environnement1",
    "Location":"Location1"
  },
  {  
    "NAME":"name2",
    "Environnement":"Environnement2",
    "Location":"Location2"
  }
]
```

Another thing is my css did not applied.

plnkr : http://plnkr.co/edit/euKrNhMmWGzIx5TnR24L?p=preview

Thanks in advance.

Comment: So you mean to say, you want to load the data from `$http` request only once in the whole application, store it in a variable, and then apply filter on the variable, am I right? If that's the case, I might have a solution.

Comment: @MohitAdwani Yes that's it.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I would suggest the following code:

**JS: (UPDATED)**

```
function DemoCtrl($timeout, $q, $log, $http) {
    var array=[];
    var self = this;
    $http.get("data.json").then(function (result) {
        array = result.data;
        init();
    function init(){
        //all other code will come inside this function
        function querySearch(query) {
              var results = query ? array.filter(createFilterFor(query)) :array;
               return results;
        }

    }
}
```

Try this out. This is what I am doing in my code. And I am using $scope variable instead of self and this. But it should work fine with you. Let me know in the comments if some errors occur.

**UPDATE**

Here is the plunkr : http://plnkr.co/edit/93nzzI?p=preview

Comment: Could you please sho this workrariund in initial plnkr : http://plnkr.co/edit/euKrNhMmWGzIx5TnR24L?p=preview ?

Comment: I updated my plnkr : http://plnkr.co/edit/euKrNhMmWGzIx5TnR24L?p=preview with suggested modification, but i deleted init() step. Could you please let le know if all is conform ?

Comment: @Widy I modified your old plunkr. Take a look at it in the answer. Meanwhile i check your modified plur

Comment: @Widy you don't have to write deferred anymore in the querySearch. Everything else is fine. I would suggest you to look at my plunkr and implement it in that way.

Comment: Great, ok it's better on writing method in your plnkr, thanks !

Comment: Yep it is solved now, thanks. And thanks to Roger too for first part of issue about getting result from URL as promise.

Comment: Only CSS is not applied, in the dropdown list, Location and Environment must be placed below NAME like example here https://material.angularjs.org/latest/#/demo/material.components.autocomplete (custom template)

Comment: @windy will take a look at it tomorrow.

Comment: @Widy Sorry. Couldn't figure out what is the problem with the CSS.

Answer (score 1):

Your `loadAll()` method returns a promise, not an array; that's why you don't have a "filter" function. You have to do the filtering inside of the promise. Perhaps something like this:

```
function querySearch(query) {
  return loadAll()
    .then(function (repos) {
      self.repos = repos.filter(createFilterFor(query));
    });
}
```

Comment: @Widy Yeah, the thing is how you're mixing the datatypes between promises and arrays. Here's a fork with little changes, nothing very functional still, you should complete it: http://plnkr.co/edit/YxNB7I7KC00OTAv2qSRH?p=preview

Comment: I found a workaround to get data from URL, but I still have issue because it is called every time (get data.json) : http://plnkr.co/edit/euKrNhMmWGzIx5TnR24L?p=preview any suggestion ?